# how to change system's COM Port settings( Bits,Data bits,Parity,Stop bits and flow control) by code in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, serial-port

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

                SerialPort MySerialPort = new SerialPort();

                txt_1.Text = MySerialPort.BaudRate.ToString();
                txt_2.Text = MySerialPort.DataBits.ToString();
                txt_3.Text = MySerialPort.Parity.ToString().ToUpper();
                txt_4.Text = MySerialPort.StopBits.ToString().ToUpper();
                txt_5.Text = MySerialPort.Handshake.ToString();
    }
}
```

It's Output will be like this.
[image: Output1]

Then i just modify the textbox values such as **7200,7,Odd,2 & Hardware**.if click Update button, those values should change in my system(Below below figure).
[image]

Finally i want to change my port settings by textbox values after i clicked the update button. What should i do for that.

Comment: Don't bother, you don't have a real serial port.  Your Bluetooth driver stack only emulates one, these settings have no effect at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those settings are stored in the registry at

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Ports`

The values are stored in a single key as a comma-separated string.

You could use something like this then:

To **read**

```
            Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey myKey = 
                Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion\\Ports", true);
            string settings = myKey.GetValue("COM3:");
```

To **write**

```
            Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey myKey = 
                Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion\\Ports", true);
            myKey.SetValue("COM3:", "9600,n,8,1");
```

But instead of writing the hard-coded `"9600,n,8,1"` value, you would construct a value from the user-supplied values in your text boxes.

Comment: This answer is very useful to me. But need another thing.How to get all values(Bits,Data bits,Parity,Stop bits and flowControl) of COM3.

Comment: @ASHOKA See the edited answer.  Is this what you're looking for?  How to read the value of COM3 settings into a string, then later write it back out.